# v3 compatible Tor client

Tags: onion-services, implementations

I am developing a tiny tor client and I need a project that is up-to-date and can browse v3 onion domains; to make it example of my own development. There are some, but almost all of them are outdated and don't support v3 onion domains. I found [arti](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/arti) but I don't know Rust. Is there any up-to-date projects besides `arti`?

P.S. The main [tor](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor) project is so massive that I don't even want to open it honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, faking development is not a good idea :) The main Tor project is brilliant, actually - and it's quite an extendable one. You'll have to learn to code to make your development - so start from the main tor project without any doubts! Godspeed!